# ASPX button click with repeater

Tags: asp.net

I have ASPX page which has a User control A in which I have a repeater with delete button xyz. I have another ASCX page which will be visible on button xyz click as popup, in this popup I have yes or no button when I click on Yes button the delete button should pass commandName as DELETE to the repeater. Can some one please help?

Comment: You say you have all these things. Supply the code that you have and ask a specific question about the problem you're having.

Comment: beside the code, its not clear if you look for javascript solution or post back solution.